# Is it possible in AMP to store amp-user-notification in cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, amp-html

By default, when the user agrees to the cookies policy, the status is saved in the local storage. Is it possible to customise saving status in to `document.cookie` with specific name something like `terms-accepted=true` ?

```
<amp-geo layout=nodisplay>
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "ISOCountryGroups": {
      "nafta": [ "ca", "mx", "us" ],
      "whereIsWaldo": [ "unknown" ],
      "anz": [ "au", "nz" ]
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-geo>

<amp-user-notification
    layout=nodisplay
    id="amp-user-notification1"
    data-show-if-not-geo="anz, nafta"
    data-dismiss-href="https://example.com/api/echo/post">
    This notice is only shown in Canada, Mexico and USA.
    <a class="btn" on="tap:amp-user-notification1.dismiss">I accept</a>
</amp-user-notification>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you set the cookie server-side using the endpoint specified via `data-dismiss-href`.